# Why does creating a branch and pushing it to the remote result in conflicts on pulling?

Tags: git

For some reason I am experiencing a problem with pulling a new branch from the remote after pushing it. I just have created a branch `test` from `master` and added some simple changes to both `test` and `master` without any kind of merging and that results in a problem:

```
git on  master 
❯ git branch test

git on  master 
❯ git st

git on  master 
❯ echo "4" >> content 

git on  master [!] took 7s 
❯ git add content 

git on  master [+] 
❯ git ci -m "added 4"
[master eff5df4] added 4
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

git on  master [⇡] 
❯ git co test
Switched to branch 'test'

git on  test 
❯ echo "5" >> content 

git on  test [!] took 6s 
❯ git add content ; git ci -m "added 5"
[test 86ec659] added 5
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

git on  test 
❯ git co master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

git on  master [⇡] 
❯ git log --oneline --all
86ec659 (test) added 5
eff5df4 (HEAD -> master) added 4
a5d72eb (tag: 0.3) added 3
84eded8 (tag: 0.2) added 3
a449cf1 (tag: 0.1, origin/master) added 3
9bf71a6 (tag: 0.0) added 3

git on  master [⇡?] 
❯ git push origin test
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 272 bytes | 272.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
remote: 
remote: Create a pull request for 'test' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/[my-repo]/pull/new/test
remote: 
To https://github.com/[my-repo].git
 * [new branch]      test -> test

git on  master  
❯ cd ../my-repo

my-repo on  master [⇡] 
❯ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 8, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 3), reused 5 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), 421 bytes | 421.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/[my-repo]
   a449cf1..eff5df4  master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      test       -> origin/test
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.

my-repo on  master [⇕] 
❯ git pull --rebase
Auto-merging content
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in content
error: could not apply 84eded8... added 3
hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 84eded8... added 3

my-repo on  HEAD (eff5df4) (REBASING 1/2) [=] 
❯ git rebase --skip
Auto-merging content
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in content
error: could not apply a5d72eb... added 3
hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply a5d72eb... added 3

my-repo on  HEAD (eff5df4) (REBASING 2/2) [=] 
❯ git rebase --skip
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

Moreover, If I try to find the branch, to which recent commits belong, it shows nothing in the cases of commits that showed up during conflict resolution:

```
my-repo on  master 
❯ git branch --contains 86ec659
  test

my-repo on  master 
❯ git branch --contains eff5df4
* master

my-repo on  master 
❯ git branch --contains a5d72eb

my-repo on  master 
❯ git branch --contains 84eded8

my-repo on  master 
❯ git branch --contains a449cf1
* master
  test

my-repo on  master 
❯ git branch --contains 9bf71a6
* master
  test
```

The same output of `git branch --contains` can be reproduced in the source repo, from which the `push` was initiated: some commits "do not have a branch". I don't know how and why this happened. Maybe I have created the tags in a wrong way?

Anyway, why does `pull` result in a conflict? I just created a standalone branch without merging, my perception is that it should not happen. How could I achieve seamless working flow with the remote? Is this a bug in `git`? My `git --version` is `2.34.1`. Thanks for the help in advance.

**PS.** Is it possible that I performed `git push --tags` without performing the `git push --all` after adding tags `0.2` and `0.3`? Just a guess.

**PS2**. Adding additional output:

```
my-repo on  master [⇡] 
❯ git log --graph --oneline --decorate test master
* eff5df4 (HEAD -> master) added 4
| * 86ec659 (origin/test, test) added 5
|/  
* a449cf1 (tag: 0.3) added 3
* 9bf71a6 (tag: 0.2) added 3
* 2c9d219 (tag: 0.1) added 3
* 85bdd34 (tag: 0.0) added 3
```

Comment: There's something missing, after executing `git ci -m "added 5"` you're suddenly back on master. What happened there?

Comment: Forgot to add the missing step as I was scrambling the history of commands from the terminal as I did some checks in between as well to understand what is happening. Updated the question.

Comment: Please show output of `git log --graph --oneline --decorate test master`

Comment: output has been added

Comment: The fact that you ran `cd ../my-repo` suggests that you have *two different checkouts of the same repository*, which will have separate local branches named "master". The remote repository you are pushing to and pulling from will also have its own branch named "master", which won't be visible in your local logs unless you use `git fetch`. These are the three branches you need to be looking at; the "test" branch is not relevant to the conflict.

Comment: Yes, what IMSoP said looks like a potential source of error/confusion. You seem to have two local clones/directories: "git" and "my-repo"

Comment: I just tried doing the same: add one commit to the `test`, another one to the `master` and `push --all`. After the `fetch --all` from another local copy `git branch --contains` for those two added commits shows nothing. No conflict though.

Comment: @altern `git branch --contains` only shows local branches. `git fetch` only updates your remote-tracking branches. Try `git branch -a --contains`

Comment: I would expect that if you run `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` in both your sandboxes, the differences in the graph should become obvious. As @IMSoP said, it's clear your `git pull` was done in a sandbox that was not in a clean state, it had to have its own commit(s) on `master` which required merging.